# How to update or add object inside arrray in vue JS 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have item list like below. I want to add new items to the list but if the id is same I want to change the value of object.

For Example :

```js
segmentValues: [
    {
        id:1,
        value:'Foo'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        value: 'Boo'
    }
],

segmentValues.push({id: 2, value:'Gogo'});
```

Now I'm pushing this new item but items list already has id = 2, so it should replace the value like below:

```js
segmentValues: [
    {
        id:1,
        value:'Foo'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        value: 'Gogo'
    }
],
```

How Can I do this in vuejs ?

Comment: You need to check if `id` exist in the array first. push if it doesn't, update otherwise. But you'll have to write some code. There's no magic method that  can help you do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if id exists in array before push:

```js
var obj = {id: 2, value:'Gogo'};
var objInArray = segmentValues.find(x => x.id === obj.id);

if (objInArray){
    objInArray = obj;
} else {
    segmentValues.push(obj);
}
```